# store the id for each <input> in v-for as my index

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, v-for

I have created several inputs using v-for and would like each input to have a unique id corresponding to the index. You can see my current code below:

```
<div v-for = "(item, index) in data" v-bind:key = "item">
    {{data[index][0]}} : {{item[1]}} <br>
    <input id = "index" placeholder =0 type="number" min="0">
<br><br> </div>
```

initially, I have used

```
<div v-for = "(item, index) in data" v-bind:key = "item">
    {{item[0]}} : {{item[1]}} <br>
    <input id = "index" placeholder =0 type="number" min="0">
<br><br> </div>
```

but VueJS require us to use the index as I have declared it in v-for.
Also, my var data is a 2D array.
Am i correct to put " id = "index" " in each input? I believe it is wrong as i cannot access the element using **document.getElementById("0").value** or **document.getElementById(0).value**

Thank you

Comment: You need to use a binding or `id` will just be the word "index":   `:id="index"`  or `v-bind:id="index"`

Comment: hi @shob thank you. Will the id be a string or number?

Comment: It's the number of the index, but probably best to think of it as a string since you're using it as an `id` attribute.  You can use either one with `document.getElementById`